# How can I move the selection in dijit editor?

Tags: dojo

I have a problem with dijit editor of dojo:

I used execCommand to insert html content at the cursor in editor like :

```
var ed = dijit.byId('myEditor');
var myDiv = "<div id='myDiv'> This is content of div </div>"
ed.focus();
ed.execCommand("inserthtml", myDiv);
```

myDiv is inserted successfully into the editor, but when I type other content in the editor, that content is within myDiv. So could you tell me how can I move the selection to be after that div ?

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to place cursor after your inserted div , then try:

```
var ed = dijit.byId('myEditor');
var myDiv = " This is content of div "
ed.focus();
ed.execCommand("inserthtml", myDiv);
ed.execCommand("inserthtml", "<br />"); //add a break tag after your new div
ed.placeCursorAtEnd(); // places cursor at the end
```

Did you mean something like this

Comment: Thanks Sudhir for quick reply! But ed.placeCursorAtEnd is only change the cursor in myDiv to the end of div not to out of that div. The problem is how can i move the cursor is out of that div.

Comment: you could try adding a <br /> tag after your new added div, hope that helps in placing the cursor out of newly added div